# Recalculating CSS padding to half its original value using "x[i].style.padding"

Tags: javascript, css, calc

I'm lost as to why this code would not work? In short Im looking at all classes named `text`, running it through a loop, and recalculating the padding to half its original value.

Maybe I'm breaking some type of rule I am not familiar with? I know you can get the value of padding using something like`alert(document.getElementById("myID").style.padding);` but I figured I should be able to use the same method for a class as long as I classified which one im targeting; Ex. [0], [1], or in my case I'm letting the loop decide.

```js
function myFunction(name) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.padding = "calc(" + x[i].style.padding + "px / 50%)";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.text {
  border: red dashed 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="text">This is a paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction('text')">Test</button>
```

Comment: you need to use computed style ... also your calc is totally wrong --> half is dividing by 2 not by 50%

Comment: Something like: `window.getComputedStyle(x[i],null).getPropertyValue("padding");`?

Comment: yes somehing like this

Comment: It returns the `px` as well as the number. Is it possible to only get the number value?

Comment: apply `parseInt`

Comment: Edit: This returns a value with the loop: `alert(parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(x[i],null).getPropertyValue("padding")) / 2 + "px")` but this breaks the function: `x[i].style.padding = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(x[i],null).getPropertyValue("padding")) / 2 + "px");`

Comment: Ah I got it, `for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      value = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(x[i],null).getPropertyValue("padding")) / 2 + "px"
      x[i].style.padding = value;
    }` Thanks for the help!